# Unable to create user using devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My code:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def testpage
    user = User.new(:email => 'test@sd.com', :encrypted_password => 'test')
    user.save
  end
end
```

I am trying to save a user manually from inside the script, but it never saves, however I am able to update the user by following code:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def testpage
    user=User.find(2)
    user.update(:email => 'new', :encrypted_password => 'new')
  end
end
```

So my second code is working fine, but not first, I don't know why.
Here is my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :manager
end
```

I have no idea what is wrong, I want to save users. I am using devise.
And I am not getting any kind of errors as well.

**edit1:**
On replacing user.save with user.save! I am getting this error.

> Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password confirmation
>   doesn't match Password

Comment: Try this: `User.new(email: 'test@sd.com', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test')`. This should work.

Comment: @Deep didn't work, any more suggestions?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Just replace `user.save` with `user.save!` and see what is the error.

Comment: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password confirmation doesn't match Password
I have both passwords as test, but still this error, weird...

Comment: Try this `User.create!(email: 'test@sd.com', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column encrypted_password where you store a hashed password is usually protected from modification. Instead few accessors provide an interface to setup the password followed by encryption.

So this is what you need:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.new
    user.email = 'new'
    user.password = user.password_confirmation = 'new'
    if user.valid?
      user.save
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end


  def update
    user = User.find(2)
    if user
      user.email = 'new'
      user.password = user.password_confirmation = 'new'
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

I suppressed errors and exception handling so make sure you cover those cases before deployment.

Comment: I am not having problems with modifications, it worked fine like I have mentioned above, I am having problem with new user creation.

Comment: Wow finally!
still the email had to validated and password greater than 8 chars, and it worked!!! thanks a lot, I had been working on this for like last 10 hours..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

```
user = User.create(email: 'test@sd.com', encrypted_password: 'test')
```

instead of

```
user = User.new(email:  'test@sd.com', encrypted_password:  'test')
user.save
```

Comment: didn't work, nothing happened, I replaced those two lines with the above line, no error and nothing is saved to database (i am using postgreSQL).
on putting user.save! after user.create, i get the same error of validation as mentioned in my post under edit1.

Comment: I think i forgot about exclamation sign after User.create. And one more thing if you have confirmable module enabled for devise, set the confirmed_at value to  Time.now while creating.

Comment: No I am not using confirmable module as you can see my user model above , I have posted that.
And I added exclaimation mark after create, getting the same error: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password confirmation doesn't match Password, even though the password is not blank at all

Comment: This is my code from "seeds.rb" from previous project "User.create!(email:"borshchov@ukr.net", password: "password")"

Comment: i did password of 8 characters for password and password confirmation, now no errors are coming but data is still not getting saved from the controller, it saved from seed.rb however

Comment: Ah sorry, ignore the message above, same error is coming again, but I was able to create new user from seed.rb , but I want to create it from a controller method